# I need to change cell format if cell is not empty using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I found the following script:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template Allocation")

    With ws
    lRow = .Range("V8" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("V8:V" & lRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

But there is syntax error, which i could not find, please, help me.

Comment: Sub Sample() Dim ws As Worksheet Dim lRow As Long Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template Allocation")

With ws
lRow = .Range("V8" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("V8:V" & lRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
End Sub

Answer (score 2):

Just change `"V8" & .Rows.Count` to  `"V8:V" & .Rows.Count`

```
With ws
    lRow = .Range("V8:V" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("V8:V" & lRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
 End With
```